# Shell - filter string that contains from email address

Tags: string, shell, logging, grep

I have a email log and I would like to print to file only senders emails address:

I have filtered the whole log using:

```
grep "to=<email@address>" input.log | grep "from=" > output.txt
```

Output is (edited for privacy):

```
Jun 26 09:21:21 X1-X5-mx postfix/cleanup[9164]: QueueID:XXX milter-reject: END-OF-MESSAGE from ipXX.ip-XX-XXX-XXX.eu[XXX.XXX.XXX.XX]: 5.7.1 Rejected by SPAM_FILTER (spam); from=<email@address> to=<email@address> proto=....
```

I would like to print to a separate file only the `from=<email@address>` part - ideally without the `from=<>` part. Senders email address is random.

Do you have any idea how to do this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fold both  `grep`s into a single `sed` or Awk script. See also [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep).

```
sed -n '/to=<email@address>/s/.*from=<\([^<>]*\).*/\1/p' input.log > output.txt
```

In brief, `sed -n` says to not print by default, the address expression `/to=<...>/` says to operate only on lines matching that regex, and the substitution command `s/...\(...\).../\1/p` says to replace the whole match with just the part within the parentheses, that is, extract just the `from=<...>` string, and `p`rint the resulting line.

If the sender address comes from a variable, you need double quotes instead of single.

```
addr='email@address'
sed -n "/to=<$addr>/s/.*from=<\([^<>]*\).*/\1/p" input.log > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `pcregrep` or a grep that has `-P`, you can do:

```
grep -F 'to=<email@address>' input.log |
grep -Po '(?<=from=<)[^>]+' > from_addresses.txt
```

- `(?<=from=<)` is a "look behind" that requires that the text preceding the desired match is "from=<", then `[^>]+` matches everything from there to the closing angle bracket
- `-o` prints only that part of the line that matches

---

Assuming postfix logs have a fixed format where `from` immediately precedes `to`, then you can use awk with a custom input field separator:

```
awk -v e='email@address' -F' (to|from)=<|>' \
    '$4==e{print $2}' input.log > from_addresses.txt
```